# Spring MVC Date format validation with JSR303

Tags: java, date, spring-mvc, format, bean-validation

I'm using Spring MVC with JSR303 to do my input validation.

A form I've created has a couple of date fields that are bound to `Date` objects within the object backing the form.  I'm using JSR303 to do the validation for the `Date` using `@Future`. I'm also using `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")`, (I know it's not validation).

How do I validate the date format of the `String` on the form?  If I leave the other required fields blank (`@NotEmpty`) and enter a non-valid date in the form 'dd/MM/yy' it gets converted to 'dd/MM/yyyy' on re-presentation (e.g. 12/03/12 is re-presented as 12/03/0012).  Which means I will get duff data in my system.  If I enter "aaa" for I get a conversion Exception.  Correctly formatted `String`s get converted to `Date` objects.

Additionally should the 'required field' annotation for `Date` fields be `@NotNull` or `@NotEmpty`?

Many thanks in advance for any advice provided.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Ralph. I did some further digging around and came up with this (Which goes in my form controller):

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {


    String format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    CustomDateEditor customDateEditor = new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat,true,format.length());

    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, customDateEditor);
    }
```

With the properties file having the following key:

`typeMismatch.java.util.Date` : Some nice calm reassuring message to assist all negligent users

Maybe there are some other ways to do this but this will do for now.

Comment: Is it possible to change message key from typeMismatch.java.util.Date to something more specific like CommandObjectXYZ.dateXYZ=Date is not valid

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this with JSR303, because the validation runs on the already poplulated (form baching) object.

So you need to implement your own custom converter, that is a bit more strickt than the one shipped with spring.

@See [Spring Reference: Chapter 6.5 Spring 3 Type Conversion](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)