# Spring REST : How to validate Date passed in request body

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation, hibernate-validator

I am working on a Spring REST application.

In that I have a REST Controller like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patient", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public BloodPressureDTO store(@RequestBody BloodPressureDTO bloodPressureDto) {

      .........
}
```

The `BloodPressureDTO` object has a `Date` object inside it.

I need to validate the `Date` object.

If the JSON that is posted in the request has an invalid date format, then I would like to handle that situation.

Comment: are you getting date in different formats in json?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/9352891/1221734

Comment: Have you found an answer yet? @soumitri

Answer (score -1):

Good news is that you are already using Spring framework which has the flexibility to be configured with both **JSR-303, JSR-349** bean validation or by implementing spring `Validator` interface to meet your requirements.

You can add `@Valid @RequestBody` to controller. The `@Valid` annotation is part of java bean validation API and is not a spring-specific construct. By adding it to the input parameter within a method in `@Controller` we will trigger validation.

You can do `@NotNull` etc simply for but for range, format, you need to extend the `Validator` & create something like `@InDateRange`

You can check date validation specific code [here](http://sterl.org/2015/06/java-jsr-validation-for-dates/).

Comment: I use @valid, annotation to validate a lot of things, my question is how to validate Date?